# Android - fragmentTransaction.replace() not works on support library 25.1.0

Tags: android, fragment, android-support-library

I replace a FrameLayout with a fragment using `fragmentTransaction.replace()`.

Layout:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/articlesAppender"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

Replacing in Activity's onCreate:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
articlesFragment = (ArticlesFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ARTICLES_FRAGMENT_TAG);

if (articlesFragment == null) {
    articlesFragment = new ArticlesFragment();
}

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.articlesAppender, articlesFragment, ARTICLES_FRAGMENT_TAG);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

ArticleFragment's onCreate:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.articles_fragment, container, false);
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    return view;
}
```

But the `view.setVisibility(View.GONE);` is not working on support library 25.1.0.
So the fragment will still be displayed on the screen.
If I set the visibility of the `articlesAppender` to `GONE`.
So it should look like this:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/articlesAppender"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">
</FrameLayout>
```

Then the the fragment will not be visible on the screen, but when I try to call `view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` later, it still not works.
The fragment still not be visible.

That means the `view` which is returned by `inflater.inflate(R.layout.articles_fragment, container, false);` is not the real view of the fragment.
But it works perfectly on support library 25.0.1.

So it's an Android's bug?

Comment: Do you want to replace frame layout with fragment?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the replace() method is not working ? If you try to setVisibility(View.GONE) on the main root element in that fragment layout instead on the inflated view, does it still not working ?

Comment: @RishabhMahatha Yes, I want to replace it. @Gil Because it works on support library 25.0.1. And I've described the situation in my question. I have to set the articlesAppender's visibility directly. That means it's not replaced. The inflated view is the root element, that's why I return this view in `onCreateView()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

issue is reported. more people seems to have this issue

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230191

Comment: And it is not the only one. They now fire onStop and onStart in a different succession when you swap 2 views. So, we should probably stick to 25.0.1 for now.

Comment: "Development team has fixed this issue" as their pm said
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230526&q=AppCompat%2025.1.0&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Comment: @Dmitry, the fix for that issue is as follows, .setAllowOptimization(false). I learned this the hard way.

Comment: @worked Yes, I know. It is mentioned in the issue I posted at code.google.com. Still, strange that they do not mention such important changes in release notes.

Comment: @worked In the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)  it says "This optimization is disabled by default." So it's not necessary to set it to false.

Comment: I still have the issue. My viewpager tabs are gone after replacing a fragment with another (viewpager is inside the fragments)

Comment: @MiloRambaldi that's for 25.1.1 recently released, which reverses the previous default behavior of 25.1.0.

Comment: I've tried 25.1.1.  The problem persists.  Reverting to 25.0.1 again.

Comment: They have fixed this problem, but maybe it's not included in 25.1.1.

Comment: I added another bug report at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=233324&sort=-opened&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a reported bug, as noted in Gillis Haasnoot's post.

I noticed that if I split replace() into remove() and add(), and use commitNow() it seems to work as expected.

Original code (fails starting with 25.1.0):

```
fragMngr.beginTransation()
    .replace(R.id.detail_container, newFrag, fragTag)
    .commit();
```

Work-around:

```
// remove old fragment
Fragment oldFrag = fragMngr.findFragmentByTag(fragTag);
if (oldFrag != null {
    fragMngr.beginTransaction().remove(oldFrag).commitNow();
}

// add new fragment
fragMngr.beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.detail_container, newFrag, fragTag)
    .commitNow();
```

Comment: OK; but think that you have a really big project that is used too many fragment transaction. It's not logical to change all commit() structures with commitNow() structures. It's really unnecessary work, isn' it?

Comment: Of course.  This is just suggested as a work-around while waiting for the actual fix.  Or you can revert to the previous version of the support library.

Comment: Good suggestion... funny thing is I'm trying this work-around but it won't work... after doing `fragMngr.beginTransaction().remove(oldFrag).commitNow();` 
The fragment is still there, checking with `fragMngr.findFragmentByTag(fragTag);` it will not return null. Even if I do a while loop, it would create an infinite loop. Any idea why?

Comment: @HugoAllexisCardona: no, I'm sorry, I don't know why.

Answer (score -1):

```
    //replace fragment
    private void replaceFragment(final Fragment newFragment, final int containerId) {
        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
         final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(containerId, newFragment, newFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
       fragmentTransaction.commit();
   }
```

**ArticleFragment's onCreate:**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.articles_fragment, container, false);
                return view;
    }

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/articlesAppender"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
```

Just call this method in your MainActivity onCreate()
Where

**newFreagment = "Fragment you want to replace with"
containerId = "Framelayout id"**