# Fragment is not visible after popbackstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager, fragment-backstack

I add fragment (home fragment) in `Activity.onCreate()`, without adding it to backstack, I do it using `FragmentTransaction.replace()`. After that i add every next fragment using `FragmentTransaction.replace()` and adding it to backstack.

I have a functionality that clears the backstack, leaving home fragment visible, to do it I use `FragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);`.

If i add only 1 fragment to backstack and then clear the backstack it works fine, but if I add more than one then after clearing the backstack the screen is blank, though the home fragment receives onStart() and onResume() and think's it's visible, it doesnt receive onPause(), onStop() until I add another fragment again or leave the app. 
Also if I `popBackstack()` one by one (on user action) it works fine, but if I `popBackstack()` in loop (popping all fragments at once) it doesnt work.

Here's the code:

```
public void changeFragment(BaseFragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack, boolean preventDuplicate) {
    Fragment topFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(fragmentContainer.getId());
    if (preventDuplicate && topFragment != null && fragment.getClass().equals(topFragment.getClass())) {
        //Prevent adding same fragment
        return;
    }

    FragmentTransaction transaction =
            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(fragmentContainer.getId(), fragment);

    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }

    transaction.commit();
}

public void goToHome() {
    fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
}
```

Comment: Try `fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()`

Comment: @KamranAhmed it didnt change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out new support library version is messing things up. After changing

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
```

back to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
```

everything works fine

Comment: I have the exact same problem, changing the library version didn't help. Are you sure that you didn't change anything within your code?

Comment: Not 100%, but I'm pretty sure I didnt change anything else.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new Method for FragmentTransaction (added in version 25.1.0) see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setAllowOptimization(boolean).

Try setting this on the FragmentTransaction while :

```
final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();    
transaction.setAllowOptimization(true);
transaction.replace(...);
```

This fixed the issue for me.

Credits to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42597413/5310016